# Xamarin: Libraries support

Tags: xamarin

I want to use a C++ library (static/dynamic) on my Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS project.
Should the C++ library be static or dynamic in order to be used on both Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS projects, as i'm thinking of using C# DLLimport/SWIG tool to use the C++ library as C#.

(I heard that iOS forbids the usage of dynamic libraries in the apps.) What can be the best approach for me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, iOS does not allow you to use dynamic libraries, so at least for iOS you must build the C++ library as a static library.

I believe both a static and a dynamic library work fine on Android, so there it doesn't matter which you choose.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as iOS8 has been released in September, you will be able to add support for iOS Embedded frameworks to all devices with a minimum deployment target of iOS8. In fact you can now add dynamic libraries when you target is not less than iOS8.
Anyways there are some pitfalls, depicted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25909870/xcode-6-and-embedded-frameworks-only-supported-in-ios8/25910262#25910262).