# Consequences of "Embedded dylibs/frameworks only run on iOS 8 or later" warning

Tags: ios, objective-c, frameworks

With Xcode 6.x we can use CocoaTouch Framework template to build a framework library and Xcode will create the .framework for us when we build, which is awesome. In our framework we want to support iOS 7.1 and up, so for Deployment Target (in our framework) we specified 7.1. Now when we build we see a warning: "Embedded dylibs/frameworks only run on iOS 8 or later". I've since read a number of blog posts on the subject that as far as running it on iOS 7.1 this warning can be ignored because it will run fine (still need to test to make sure). What concerns me is that I read a post on Stack Overflow which says an app may be rejected by Apple in the App Store (see: [Xcode 6 and Embedded Frameworks only supported in iOS8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25909870/xcode-6-and-embedded-frameworks-only-supported-in-ios8/25910262#25910262))

Does it only apply when in Xcode the app links to it in General > Embedded Libraries?

The way we want our customers to link to our framework is:

1. Via CocoaPods
2. By referencing .framework in Build Phase > Link Binary With Libraries

I need to understand under what conditions App Store will reject an app which uses our CocoaTouch framework and supports 7.x iOS.

Comment: Use try it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32516800/embedded-dylibs-frameworks-are-only-supported-on-ios-8-0-and-later-for-architect/36212682#36212682][1]

Answer (score 3):

The app wont be rejected if you'll change the type of your framework to **Static**. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28703657/1041469).

Answer (score 1):

I believe that as long as the app deals with the framework correctly there shouldn't be any issues. Mixing with cocoapods could be tricky and honestly I don't know the best way to tackle it.

But from what I understand, if an app supports iOS 7.X -> 8.X and uses an embedded cocoa touch framework, as long as the compatibility checks are there to ensure the app doesn't crash in 7.X, there shouldn't be any reason for the app to be rejected.

Comment: That being said the purpose of embedded framework is to share code between app and extension. Will I need to extract the code from the framework and add it to the project separately to support iOS 7? If so that will defeat the point of embedded frameworks.

Comment: Unfortunately I believe that is the case. Purely because iOS7 doesn't know that they exist. Might be worth some investigation. It might work on a, the framework is bundled in the app. iOS treats it like any other framework that has been bundled. But I think there would be issues with the signature of the Framework.

Answer (score 0):

We tried running the latest code on the following configurations:

iOS 8+   — iPhone 5s
iOS 7.1.2 — iPhone 4
iOS 6.1.3 — iPad 4

The App is working fine on all the three devices but the warning is present in the Xcode while compiling .
"embedded dylibs/frameworks only run on iOS 8 or later”

Also I tried to Archive the App in order to submit it to the app store it went on fine.

Also,  found out a link where in an apple developer stated this to be a bug:
https://devforums.apple.com/message/999579#999579