# Embedded dylibs/frameworks are only supported on iOS 8.0 and later for architecture armv7

Tags: ios, xcode

I just upgraded from Xcode 6.4 to Xcode 7GM and am now getting the following warning when running my old project

```
embedded dylibs/frameworks are only supported on iOS 8.0 
and later (@rpath/xxxxxx.framework/xxxxxx) for architecture armv7
```

This problem only happens in Xcode 7.But when I run the project in Xcode 6.4,it has never happened.

Comment: What is your deployment target?

Comment: My deployment target is 7.1.But only when I run it in Xcode 7 , the problem happens

Comment: I've just had the same error (for the first time) when upgrading to Xcode 9.2.  Good to see that Xcode's user-unfriendliness is as consistent today as it was in 2015.  The fix was to update the "iOS Deployment Target" to 8.0 or later in the Project's "Build Settings" *and* in each of the sub-project's "Build Settings" aswell.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I experience the exact same issue on Xcode 7.1 beta3, and what I do is to search keyword 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' to make sure all targets above 8.0.

Comment: what should I do if I want to support minimum deployment minimum OS version as 7.0 but library supports 8.0+ ??

Answer (score 10):

- I had a bug when updating xcode to ver 7.3. I had a solution for me. I think it useful!

[image: attack]

Comment: This worked for me. For some reason separate Pods have not correct deployment target.

Answer (score 7):

Make sure **all your TARGETs has same deployment target** (installed pods or framework too) .

For example in below example all targets (Bolts,FBSDKCoreKit, FBSDKLoginKit .... SingleSignOnPod) must have same target (say 7.0)..

[image]

Comment: Damn, you were right.  Changing the Deployment Target on the main project is not enough.  Why *is* Xcode so damn unfriendly..?!

Answer (score 1):

Your deployment target is lower than 8.0, which is the lowest iOS version that supports embedded frameworks. If you deploy the app on a device running 7.x, it would crash at runtime. This is why the compiler gave this warning.

The reason why this didn't happen on Xcode 6.4 is unknown. I myself dose get the warning when I did the same thing (chose deployment target 7.x but used embedded frameworks).

To solve this, just raise the deployment target to 8.0 or above. If you do need to support 7.x, try to use static libraries instead of embedded frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have any embedded frameworks in my project, but this problem was because of the Thread Sanitizer turned on.

So the workaround was to raise deployment target to iOS 8, then debug threading issues, and then turn Thread Sanitizer off and bring back iOS 7 support.