# How to run Modern Frameworks on iOS 7 and iOS8

Tags: ios, xcode6.1, ios-frameworks

I have created the new modern frameworks in iOS 8, I am not sure it is not running on iOS 7, what do I need to to run modern frameworks on iOS 7??

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25909870/xcode-6-and-embedded-frameworks-only-supported-in-ios8

Answer (score 0):

You must do the linking work manually for iOS 7.  See Apple's document "Deploying a Containing App to Older Versions of iOS" 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH21-SW3

Comment: Can you expand on this?  I've read this document a few times and it sounds like you can't use embedded frameworks on iOS7: "Call the dlopen command only if your containing app is running in iOS 8.0 or later."  If so your answer should be that it can't be done.