# Archive validation failed with errors during app store distribution process

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, ipa, alamofire

I have been trying to send my application to apple for submission and it is my first experience about it. I have searched the errors and applied all suggested solutions. However none of the solutions didn't work for me. I got the error below. 
[image]

I set the ios deployment target as ios 7.0 and later versions for both of the project target and Alamofire framework. Also, my Xcode version is 6.1.1 . However, I could not understand that why not working.

Could you help me please ?

Thank you for your answers

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, iOS 7 does not support frameworks. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26203659/1342462) is some additional information about it. The known workaround is to add Alamofire to your project by dragging the Alamofire.swift file directly into your project.

> A good way to track this type of usage in your project is to use Git submodules. You could also download a version and copy the file into your project, but then it gets more difficult to track what version you have compiled into your project.

This will build Alamofire into your project as though it was just another Swift file associated with your project.

> This is also why most Swift CocoaPods are iOS 8 only.