# embedded dylibs/frameworks are only supported on iOS 8.0 and later

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, reactjs, react-native

I have made react-native integrated with my existing app. But it can only run on iOS 8.0 or later. As many programmers said, react-native can run on iOS 7.0, but I didn't make it work. And there are the compiling error messages from xcode:

ld: embedded dylibs/frameworks are only supported on iOS 8.0 and later (@rpath/React.framework/React) for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Anyone can tell me how could I solve this problem to make react-native to run on iOS 7.0?

Comment: Check answer here: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/28703657/5575752](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28703657/5575752)

Comment: I have tried this, but it didn't work..@Ronak Chaniyara