# ITMS 90362 - Issues submitting app to Apple store

Tags: ios, frameworks, app-store, info.plist, ios9.3

I have created one framework which uses APNS using Xcode 7.2.1 which I am using in my App and trying to upload the build to the AppStore.  While uploading app to the AppStore I am getting the issue below.  [image: I am getting this error while uploading build to the App Store]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use dynamic frameworks with iOS 7 and before.  You will either have to update your app to a minimum OS level of 8.0 or not use the framework.

There appear to be other potential alternatives that allow you to do conditional linking, but that is dependent on what the framework is used for.  If it's optional functionality, that solution may work for you.  If it's something critical, like in the network communications, you are out of luck.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29571923/3708242)'s some details.

Comment: Thanks wottle for this information, Is there any way, so I can give support for iOS 7 to my App with such framework ?

Comment: Well, you won't be able to sue the framework in the app under iOS 7, but if it is a feature that you only need to offer in iOS8, but the rest of the app works without the framework in iOS 7, you can use the link at the end of the answer to do that.